# SQL Server Express 2012 [Builtin\Users] not found in Spanish Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-express, collation

My application silently installs SQL Server Express 2012 with these parameters:

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /Q /HIDECONSOLE=1 /ACTION=INSTALL /ENU 
        /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" /FEATURES=SQLENGINE 
        /INSTANCENAME=MyInstance /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="password" 
        /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=AUTOMATIC /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 
        /UPDATEENABLED=0 /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=1 /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck
```

Notice it uses `Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

After the installation I run a configuration script that includes, among many other things, this command:

```
deny create database to [BUILTIN\Users];
```

All is fine if I install on US Windows 10 x64. However, if I try installing on non-English Windows 10 x64, say Spanish Windows, this command generates this error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Server DESKTOP-QFSDJG3\EEM01, Line 1
>   Cannot find the user 'BUILTIN\Users', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

However, if I run this query, it is clear that [BUILTIN\Users] is there:

```
select name from sys.syslogins
```

I know I have the permissions because I am connecting as SA. I assume this is some kind of collation issue. Any clues what might be going wrong?

Comment: Check the permission to that particular user.

Comment: The user is SA so it should have the required permissions.